# underscorejs filtered out `0` values when use ''

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var progress = _.filter($scope.Event.Item.Progress, function (u) { return u.TotalUnitsCompleted != ''; });
```

**[underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)**

Could you tell me why above filtered out `0` values also ? I just need to filter the `''` values only.

Comment: `!=` makes type coercion when comparing different types of values. Use `!==` instead.

Comment: @Teemu Oh.. Thanks a lot.Can you put it as an answer ? Then I can close this pots.

Comment: This question might be a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: @Teemu But context is different no ?

Comment: In the question yes, but answers stand for your question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because

```
0 == '' //true
```

in javscript.
to get sane comparisons you should use

```
0 === '' // false
```

or in your case:

```
!== ''
```